# Truecrypt password issue, have recovery disk

Tags: encryption, truecrypt

I am trying to log in to a laptop that has not been used since the end of last year. The laptop has Truecrypt 7.1 along with Windows 7.

I am 99% sure I am using the correct password. On entering the believed to be correct password I am met with an `Incorrect Password` message but not  `Incorrect password or no TrueCrypt volume found`.

I have the recovery cd and hoped this would provide an easy fix but due to my lack of experience where such matters are concerned I am unsure how to proceed with the use of the features offered on the cd.

Other points of consideration:

At start up the laptop automatically goes into Windows startup repair mode.

The laptop was recently with an ex girlfriend who threatened to damage the laptop! although on return I can see no obvious physical sign of damage to the machine - considering the laptop-s current state / issues could any attempts at damage have caused these issues?

Access is highly desired without wiping the system in anyway as lots of sentimental material is present which cannot be replaced.

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: Unless she changed the password it would seem to be a case of you simply forgetting your password. A recovery disc won't get you round a bootloader password. I am sure you can find a hack or brute for method of getting round it.

Comment: No, a good pw cannot be brute-forced and TC has no known vulnerabilities to allow a hack.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused as to your requirements, since you state you're trying to use a TrueCrypt Rescue Disc but the system also boots to Windows Startup Repair.

What sort of TrueCrypt volume are you trying to unlock? There are three kinds:

1. TrueCrypt Container - A file on a (usually non-encrypted) drive which itself contains the files protected by TrueCrypt.
2. Encrypted Non-System Volume - A drive or partition that is fully encrypted, but is not the same volume which contains your Operating System.
3. Encrypted System Volume - A drive or partition which is fully encrypted, and contains your Operating System.

*Usually*, the third is the only one for which a TrueCrypt Rescue Disc is made. However, if your system volume was encrypted, you would not be able to get to Windows Startup Repair without first logging into TrueCrypt - the TrueCrypt bootloader runs first, and (upon successful login) then starts Windows.

If the system volume is encrypted, you have three basic options for logging in:

1. Log into the TrueCrypt bootloader with the ***current*** TrueCrypt password and/or key files (collectively referred to as "authenticators" later on).

   - i.e.: Normal TrueCrypt boot process.
2. Use the TrueCrypt Rescue Disc to boot the system, and log in with the TrueCrypt authenticators which were in place ***at the time the Rescue Disc was created***.

   - Rescue Disc authenticator configurations don't get updated when you change a volume password - if you want to have a Rescue Disc with the current authenticator configuration after a change, you'll need to make a new one.
   - The purpose of the Rescue Disc in this case is to fix one of two problems: 1.) You've forgotten or lost the current authenticators, but have access to the authenticators that were used when the Rescue Disc was created. 2.) The TrueCrypt key or bootloader on the system is corrupted, so you're using the backup key and bootloader on the Rescue Disc as a temporary stand-in.
3. Remove the HDD and attach it to a working system which has TrueCrypt installed. Then, unlock the volume using the "Mount Without Pre-Boot Authentication" option under the "System" menu. You will need to log in with the ***current*** TrueCrypt authenticators.

   - This bypasses the need to worry about bootloaders, or the possibly broken OS on the encrypted system, entirely. It's also generally easier to back up a system from a different live system anyway.

Comment: It is the 3rd option full encrypted system volume.

When i turn on the computer it goes straight to the Windows Repair Mode screen instead of the Truecrypt Bootloader. The only way i can be prompted for a password is through the recovery CD. It is as if there is no Truecrypt volume showing on the laptop. Could the issue actually be with Windows then rather than me getting the password wrong? Could the files be damaged?

I am not very well versed in this field however i will look to find someone to remove the HDD and put it in a working system.

Thanks for your help